# CUSPARSE tridiagonal solver `cusparseDgtsv` is slow

Tags: cuda, numerical-methods

I'm solving a system of linear equations with dedicated solver `cusparseDgtsv()` from CUSPARSE library and find it produce no acceleration. 
I tried running tests at:

- Device 0: "Tesla K40s"
- CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          9.2 / 9.1
- CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    3.5
- Itel Xeon E5-2697 v3 2.60GHz

The next test code i compile with `nvcc -lcusparse main.cu -o dgtsv.app -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35` for *Tesla K40s*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cusparse.h>

void run_Dgtsv_test(int n);
void run_Managed_Dgtsv_test(int n);

int tridiagonalmatrixalgorithm(double* a, double* b, double* c, double* d, double** X, int size);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

        int base = 2;
    int max_size = (INT_MAX/16)/(sizeof(double));

    printf("Dgtsv speed test\n SLAE size, Dgtsv time, Serial \n");
    for (int n = 512; n < max_size; n*=base)
        run_Dgtsv_test(n);

    printf("####################### Testing MANAGED Malloc ###########################\n");

    printf("Managed malloc Dgtsv speed test\n SLAE size, Dgtsv time, Serial \n");
    for (int n = 512; n < max_size; n*=base)
        run_Managed_Dgtsv_test(n);


}

/**
  * run cuSPARSE solver for tridiagonal matrix
  */
void run_Dgtsv_test(int n) {
    // {{{
    cusparseHandle_t cusparseHandle;
    cusparseStatus_t cusparseStatus;
    cusparseStatus = cusparseCreate(&cusparseHandle);

    double* a_dev;
    double* b_dev;
    double* c_dev;
    double* d_dev;

    double* a;
    double* b;
    double* c;
    double* d;
    double* tmp;

    int num_of_tests = 50;

    a = new double[n]; // lower diagonal
    b = new double[n]; // main diagonal
    c = new double[n]; // upper diagonal
    d = new double[n]; // right handside part
    tmp = new double[n];

    for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = 0;
        b[i] = 0;
        c[i] = 0;
        d[i] = 0;

        tmp[i] = i;
    }

    for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        b[i] = 4*i;
        d[i] = 8*i;
    }
    for (int i=1; i < n-1; i++) {
      a[i] = i;
      c[i] = 2*i;
    }

    size_t size = sizeof(double) * n;
    (cudaMalloc( (void**)& a_dev , size) );
    (cudaMalloc( (void**)& b_dev , size) );
    (cudaMalloc( (void**)& c_dev , size) );
    (cudaMalloc( (void**)& d_dev , size) );

    cudaMemcpy( a_dev, a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy( b_dev, b, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy( c_dev, c, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy( d_dev, d, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);



    /* ------------------------------ cuSPARSE TEST ---------------------------------------------- */
    clock_t t1 = clock();
    for (int i=0; i < num_of_tests; i++) {
        cusparseStatus = cusparseDgtsv(cusparseHandle, n, 1, a_dev,b_dev,c_dev,d_dev, n);
        if ( cusparseStatus != CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS ) {
            fprintf(stderr,"Failed to perform CUSPARSE Dgtsv: int Dgtsv test\n");
            throw;
        }
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    }
    clock_t t2 = clock();
    /* ----------------------------------- serial test ------------------------------------------- */
    for (int i=0; i < num_of_tests; i++) {
        tridiagonalmatrixalgorithm(a,b,c,d,&tmp,n);
    }
    clock_t t3 = clock();

    double time1 = ((double) (t2 - t1)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC / num_of_tests;
    double time2 = ((double) (t3 - t2)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC / num_of_tests;

    printf("(%9.d, %9.6f, %9.6f) \n",n,time1,time2);

    (cudaFree( a_dev ) );
    (cudaFree( b_dev ) );
    (cudaFree( c_dev ) );
    (cudaFree( d_dev ) );
    delete[] (a);
    delete[] (b);
    delete[] (c);
    delete[] (d);
    cusparseDestroy(cusparseHandle);
}
// }}}

/**
 * run cuSPARSE solver for tridiagonal matrix
 */
void run_Managed_Dgtsv_test(int n) {
    // {{{
    cusparseHandle_t cusparseHandle;
    cusparseStatus_t cusparseStatus;
    cusparseStatus = cusparseCreate(&cusparseHandle);

    double* a_dev;
    double* b_dev;
    double* c_dev;
    double* d_dev;

    double* a;
    double* b;
    double* c;
    double* d;
    double* tmp;

    int num_of_tests = 50;

    a = new double[n];
    b = new double[n];
    c = new double[n];
    d = new double[n];
    tmp = new double[n];

    for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = 0;
        b[i] = 0;
        c[i] = 0;
        d[i] = 0;

        tmp[i] = i;
    }

    for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        b[i] = 4*i;
        d[i] = 8*i;
    }
    for (int i=1; i < n-1; i++) {
      a[i] = i;
      c[i] = 2*i;
    }

    size_t size = sizeof(double) * n;
    (cudaMallocManaged( (void**)& a_dev , size) );
    (cudaMallocManaged( (void**)& b_dev , size) );
    (cudaMallocManaged( (void**)& c_dev , size) );
    (cudaMallocManaged( (void**)& d_dev , size) );

    cudaMemcpy( (void **) &a_dev, a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy( (void **) &b_dev, b, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy( (void **) &c_dev, c, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy( (void **) &d_dev, d, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);



    /* ------------------------------ cuSPARSE TEST ---------------------------------------------- */
    clock_t t1 = clock();
    for (int i=0; i < num_of_tests; i++) {
        cusparseStatus = cusparseDgtsv(cusparseHandle, n, 1, a_dev,b_dev,c_dev,d_dev, n);
        if ( cusparseStatus != CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS ) {
            fprintf(stderr,"Failed to perform CUSPARSE Dgtsv: int Dgtsv test\n");
            throw;
        }
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    }
    clock_t t2 = clock();
    /* ----------------------------------- serial test ------------------------------------------- */
    for (int i=0; i < num_of_tests; i++) {
        tridiagonalmatrixalgorithm(a,b,c,d,&tmp,n);
    }
    clock_t t3 = clock();


    double time1 = ((double) (t2 - t1)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC / num_of_tests;
    double time2 = ((double) (t3 - t2)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC / num_of_tests;

    printf("(%9.d, %9.6f, %9.6f) \n",n,time1,time2);

    (cudaFree( a_dev ) );
    (cudaFree( b_dev ) );
    (cudaFree( c_dev ) );
    (cudaFree( d_dev ) );
    delete[] (a);
    delete[] (b);
    delete[] (c);
    delete[] (d);
    cusparseDestroy(cusparseHandle);
}
// }}}


/** Serial tridiagonal solver
 *
 * Tridiagonal algorithm, same array size for all input vars.
 * @var X, @var a, @var b, @var  should be size of @var n
 * **************************************************************************************************
 * **** Warning! b[0] and c[n-1] is a trash element, but they should be for array size constancy ****
 * **************************************************************************************************
 * @input double**              X       -- pointer to array where the answer will be written
 *
 * ⬇︎ b[0]
 *      | a c 0 0 0 0 ... 0 0 0 | | x | = | d |
 *      | b a c 0 0 0 ... 0 0 0 | | x | = | d |
 *      | 0 b a c 0 0 ... 0 0 0 | | x | = | d |
 *      | 0 0 b a c 0 ... 0 0 0 | | x | = | d |
 *      | :                   : | | x | = | d |
 *      | :                   : | | x | = | d |
 *      | 0 ...           b a c | | x | = | d |
 *      | 0 ...           0 b a | | x | = | d |
 *                                                               ⬆︎ c[n-1]
 */

int tridiagonalmatrixalgorithm(double* a, double* b, double* c, double* d, double** X, int size) {
    // {{{

    double* x = (double*) calloc(size,sizeof(double));
    double* v = (double*) calloc(size,sizeof(double));
    double w;
    w = a[0];
    x[0] = d[0]/w;
    for (int i=1; i<size; i++) {
        v[i-1] = c[i-1]/w;
        w = a[i] - b[i]*v[i-1];
        x[i] = (d[i] - b[i]*x[i-1])/w;
    }

    for (int j=size-2; j >= 0; j--)
      x[j] = x[j] - v[j] * x[j+1];

    for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
      (*X)[i] = x[i];
    free(v);
    free(x);
    return 0;
}
// }}}
```

That gives me next output:

```
Dgtsv speed test
 SLAE size, Dgtsv time, Serial
(      512,  0.000600,  0.000200)
(     1024,  0.001000,  0.000000)
(     2048,  0.000800,  0.000200)
(     4096,  0.001000,  0.000200)
(     8192,  0.000800,  0.000200)
(    16384,  0.001000,  0.000200)
(    32768,  0.001600,  0.000600)
(    65536,  0.001800,  0.001400)
(   131072,  0.002000,  0.002600)
(   262144,  0.003000,  0.005400)
(   524288,  0.005000,  0.011600)
(  1048576,  0.008400,  0.023000)
(  2097152,  0.015800,  0.045400)
(  4194304,  0.030400,  0.090200)
(  8388608,  0.059600,  0.192800)
####################### Testing MANAGED Malloc ###########################
Managed malloc Dgtsv speed test
 SLAE size, Dgtsv time, Serial
(      512,  0.001000,  0.000000)
(     1024,  0.001400,  0.000000)
(     2048,  0.001200,  0.000000)
(     4096,  0.001400,  0.000000)
(     8192,  0.001200,  0.000200)
(    16384,  0.001200,  0.000400)
(    32768,  0.001400,  0.000600)
(    65536,  0.001800,  0.001400)
(   131072,  0.002400,  0.002600)
(   262144,  0.003000,  0.005600)
(   524288,  0.004800,  0.011000)
(  1048576,  0.008600,  0.022000)
(  2097152,  0.015800,  0.045800)
(  4194304,  0.030600,  0.091200)
(  8388608,  0.059800,  0.179600)
```

Compiler versions

```
$ nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Jan_10_13:22:03_CST_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.61


$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

What I'm missing?
Thank you!

Comment: I can see only [`cusparseDgtsv_nopivot`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#gtsv_nopivot) function in the documentation, which is even now marked as deprecated. However, this function requires the `du` array representing the upper diagonal to have the last element equal zero. In your code, `c[n-1]` is non-zero.

Comment: Moreover, it seem to me that your input matrix is singular. Namely, all the elements of the first matrix row are zero. Even in your CPU version of the solver, you first set `w=a[0];`, and `a[0]==0` (due to `a[i]=i;`). Then you divide by `w` producing division by zero.

Comment: The obvious advice would be not to use managed memory. That is extremely slow by its very nature

Comment: @DanielLangr thx for your comments. I did some fixes to my code, but this didn't affect performance. I'm using [cusparseDgtsv](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/9.2/cusparse/index.html#cusparse-lt-t-gt-gtsv) from CUDA 9.2 toolkit

Comment: @talonmies my college reported that this function works 10 times faster if allocate managed memory. She used GTX 1050. Anyway i added tests with `cudaMalloc` and it is only 1.2 times faster then `cudaMallocManaged` version.

Comment: It looks to me like at sizes of 131072 and larger, cusparse appears to be faster. Also, to get the most performance out of Tesla K40, its necessary to manually boost the clocks using `nvidia-smi`.  If you haven't done this, it won't make a huge difference in your results but may boost the GPU performance by ~20% or more.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I'm working on my university's cluster, so I'm not allowed to boost anything. I see the speed up after > 130k variables, but it is ridiculously small.
Is this really maximum that CUSPARSE can propose?

Comment: 3x speedup is ridiculously small?  Also, the Tesla K40 is about 6 years old.  When I ran your code on a machine with a Tesla P100 (about 3 years old) I witnessed 10x speedup.  But obviously the speedup will depend on your CPU also, and I don't think your CPU code is well optimized.  A reasonable expectation for comparing well optimized CPU and GPU codes is 5x speedup for the GPU. You are in the ballpark. If you were expecting 50x, you need to reset your expectations. Furthermore, GPUs work better on larger problems, so expecting interesting performance at the small problem sizes is unrealistic

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is effectively about the OP's unreasonable performance expectations not being satisfied, rather than a real programming problem